# How to clone a jQuery object and add it as a sibling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a box using a `div`.

```
<div class="panel" style="display:inline; float:left;position: relative; width: 140px; height: 200px; border:solid 2px; border-color: red;cursor: pointer;"></div>
```

I tried to use jQuery to clone the element and append the clone to itself, but it doesn't work as expected.

```
for (; i < noC; i++) {
    $(".panel").clone().appendTo($(".panel"));
}
```

I want each box to be added after the last box.

```
[]     // noC = 1
[][]   // noC = 2
[][][] // noC = 3
```

Instead, each new box gets inserted inside of the previous box.

```
[]     // noC = 1
[[]]   // noC = 2
[[[]]] // noC = 3
```

How do I do that?

Comment: you get any errors?
could you post a fiddle ex?

Comment: no error. the code works fine. the output is not given for the box is not what i wanted. it stack over each other. [[]] like this i want it be [] [] [] [] [] like this in column form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
noC = 3;
for(i= 0; i < noC;i++) {
    $("#panel").append(function(){     
        return $("#panel").find('div').length==0?$(this).clone(): $("#panel").find('div:first').clone();
    });
}​
```

for live demo see this link: http://jsfiddle.net/nanoquantumtech/PBBNe/
//Or

```
     noC = 3;
    for(i= 0; i < noC;i++) {
    $("body").append($("#panel:first").clone());        
     }​
```

for live demo see this link: http://jsfiddle.net/nanoquantumtech/HvnbU/

Answer (score 1):

[Check this out](http://jsfiddle.net/p8AfA/14/). Don't forget that you can modify cloned element before append,prepend,inserting it to other element. This is the snippet:

```
noC = 5;
for(var i = 0; i < noC; i++) {
    var panel = $('.panel').filter(':first').clone();
    panel.text('panel ' +i);
    $('.panel').filter(':last').after(panel);
}
```

I use filter :last in case to place the cloned element next to the last element :-D

Answer (score 1):

The answers above that I can see mostly reference elements by classes, so I'd consider this a bit more flexible:

```
const cloneAsSibling = element => {
  element.clone().insertAfter(element);
}
```

I used it in an .each() loop in my project.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though you have some syntax errors and might be trying to clone the wrong thing.

```
var i = 0;
var noC = 3;
for(i=0; i < noC; i++){
    $('#panel').clone().appendTo('.a');
}
```

Note that I changed it from `.panel` to `#panel`

Answer (score 0):

Check this.I think you are trying to clone the `panel`:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p8AfA/1/)

Comment: not this. i don't want different row. but thanks. i don't use id for same div.

Answer (score 0):

```
var noC = 2;
    cloned = $('.panel').clone();
for(i= 0; i < noC;i++) {
    cloned.appendTo($(".panel"));
}​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/D5cHR/1/)**

You can device a function if you want several times:

```
function appendClones(target, times) {
    var noC = times;
        cloned = $(target).clone();
    for(i= 0; i < noC;i++) {
        cloned.appendTo($(target));
    }​
}
```

Call the function:  `appendClones('.panel', 3);`

**NOTE:** change the id `#panel` to class `.panel`. Because multiple `id` is not allowed.

Comment: the output in it show what i get exactly from my code. i want it to be
2 box side by side. not overlapping each other.

Answer (score 0):

I solve that with "after" http://api.jquery.com/after/

show my example here http://jsfiddle.net/gastonnina/Mf2dE/2/

```
<script>
function cloname(that){
    var li = $(that).closest('li');
    var clon = li.clone();
clon.html(clon.html()+" clonado");
li.after( clon );
}     
</script>
<ul>
    <li>Contenido1 <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:cloname(this);">CLONA</a></li>
</ul>
```